# Не понимаю, почему мой код выдаёт ошибку

Tags: 1с, авторизация

Не понимаю, почему мой код выдаёт ошибку, я студент, так что ошибка может быть очень тупой, но я уже не знаю что делать

Кучу времени уже потратил на различные форумы и видео по 1С, но так и не понял, как решить мою проблему с кодом. Вот сам код.

и ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код в текстовом формате.

```
Запрос = новый Запрос;
    Запрос.Текст = "ВЫБРАТЬ
     |  Пользователь.Логин КАК Логин,
     |  Пользователь.УникальныйИдентификатор КАК УникальныйИдентификатор
     |ИЗ
     |  Справочник.Пользователь КАК Пользователь
     |ГДЕ
     |  Пользователь.Логин = &Логин";
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Логин", Объект.Логин);
    Результат = Запрос.Выполнить().Выбрать();  
    
    Если Результат.Следующий() тогда
        Если Результат.Количество() = 0 ИЛИ ТекущийОбъект.УникальныйИдентификатор = Результат.УникальнйыйИдентификатор тогда
            ПользовательСсылка = ПользовательИнформационнойБазы.НайтиПоУникальномуИдентификатору(Текущий.УникальныйИдентификатор);
            Если ПользовательСсылка = Неопределено тогда
                НовыйПользователь = ПользователиИнформационнойБазы.СоздатьПользователя();
                НовыйПользователь.Имя = Объект.Логин;
                НовыйПользователь.Пароль = Объект.Пароль;
                НовыйПользователь.ПолноеИмя = Объект.Наименование;
                Если Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Администратор тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роль.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Администратор);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Менеджер тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Менеджер);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Директор тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Директор);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Замерщик тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Замерщик);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Мастер тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить (Метаданные.Роли.Мастер);
                КонецЕсли;
                НовыйПользователь.ПоказыватьВСпискеВыбора = Ложь;
                НовыйПользователь.Записать();
                ТекущийОбъект.УникльныйИдентификатор = НовыйПользователь.УникальныйИдентификатор;
            Иначе 
                ПользовательСсылка.Пароль = Объект.Пароль;
                ПользовательСсылка.ПолноеИмя = Объект.Наименование;
                ПользовательСсылка.Роли.очистить();
                Если Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Администратор тогда
                    ПользовательСсылка.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Администратор);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Менеджер тогда
                    ПользовательСсылка.Роли.Добавить (Метаданные.Роли.Менеджер);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = перечисления.Роли.Мастер тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Мастер);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Мастер тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Мастер);
                КонецЕсли;
            Иначе
                Сообщ = Новый СообщениеПользователю;
                Сообщ.Текст = "Пользователь с таким именем уже существует";
                Сообщ.Сообщить();
                Отказ = Истина;
            КонецЕсли;
        КонецЕсли;
        
        Иначе
            НовыйПользователь = ПользователиИнформационнойБазы.СоздатьПользователя();
            НовыйПользователь.Имя = Объект.Логин;
            НовыйПользователь.Пароль = Объект.Пароль;
            НовыйПользователь.ПолноеИмя = Объект.Наименование;
            Если Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Администратор тогда
                НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Администратор);
            ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Менеджер тогда
                ПользовательСсылка.Роли.Добавить (Метаданные.Роли.Менеджер);
            ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = перечисления.Роли.Мастер тогда
                НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Мастер);
            ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Мастер тогда
                НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Мастер);
        КонецЕсли;
            НовыйПользователь.ПоказыватьВСпискеВыбора = Ложь;
            НовыйПользователь.Записать();
            ТекущийОбъект.УникальныйИдентификатор = НовыйПользователь.УникальныйИдентификатор;
        КонецЕсли;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Не приводите код/данные кртинкой.

Comment: Я попробую отредактировать постЮ добавив в него код, но я не уверен в том, что он влезет

Comment: Влезет. [Почему в вопросе не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120) Вот правило.

Comment: Буду теперь знать

Comment: Явно не может быть две ветки `Иначе ` в одном условии.

Comment: Вряд-ли ошибка в ветках Иначе, по крайней мере, ошибка с ней не выскакивает, главная ошибка с неопределенной переменной.

Comment: Ну да, ну да. Два `Иначе ` могут быть, ведь это два разных случая иначе, ага.

Comment: Окей, я приму к сведению ошибку с Иначе, но на данный момент мне нужно решить проблему с неопределённой переменной, можете подсказать, как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с пользователями используйте **ПользователиИнформационнойБазы** вместо **ПользовательИнформационнойБазы**

Описание в документации:

ПользователиИнформационнойБазы (InfoBaseUsers)
**Использование:**
Только чтение.
**Описание:**
Тип: МенеджерПользователейИнформационнойБазы.
Используется для управления списком пользователей информационной базы.
**Доступность:**
Сервер, толстый клиент, внешнее соединение, мобильное приложение(сервер).

А вот результатом работы поиска будет объект **ПользовательИнформационнойБазы**

Пример:
`Пользователь = ПользователиИнформационнойБазы.НайтиПоУникальномуИдентификатору(Идентификатор);`

Comment: Это безусловно очень полезный совет, но я ничего не понял, извини

Comment: @Programm_problem дополнил ответ, у вас опечатка. А так РТФМ

Answer (score 0):

У вас синтаксические ошибки.

1. нет ключевого слов Процедура и КонецПроцедуры;
2. элементы справочника создаются при помощи метода СоздатьЭлемент()
   Должно быть вот так примерно:

   Процедура ЛюбоеИмяПроцедуры()
   Запрос = новый Запрос;
   Запрос.Текст = "ВЫБРАТЬ
   |  Пользователь.Логин КАК Логин,
   |  Пользователь.УникальныйИдентификатор КАК УникальныйИдентификатор
   |ИЗ
   |  Справочник.Пользователь КАК Пользователь
   |ГДЕ
   |  Пользователь.Логин = &Логин";
   Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Логин", Объект.Логин);
   Результат = Запрос.Выполнить().Выбрать();

   ```
    Если Результат.Следующий() тогда
        Если Результат.Количество() = 0 ИЛИ ТекущийОбъект.УникальныйИдентификатор = Результат.УникальнйыйИдентификатор тогда
            ПользовательСсылка = Справочники.ПользовательИнформационнойБазы.НайтиПоУникальномуИдентификатору(Текущий.УникальныйИдентификатор);
            Если ПользовательСсылка = Неопределено тогда
                НовыйПользователь = Справочники.ПользователиИнформационнойБазы.СоздатьЭлемент();
                НовыйПользователь.Имя = Объект.Логин;
                НовыйПользователь.Пароль = Объект.Пароль;
                НовыйПользователь.ПолноеИмя = Объект.Наименование;
                Если Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Администратор тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роль.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Администратор);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Менеджер тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Менеджер);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Директор тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Директор);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Замерщик тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Замерщик);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Мастер тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить (Метаданные.Роли.Мастер);
                КонецЕсли;
                НовыйПользователь.ПоказыватьВСпискеВыбора = Ложь;
                НовыйПользователь.Записать();
                ТекущийОбъект.УникльныйИдентификатор = НовыйПользователь.УникальныйИдентификатор;
            Иначе 
                ПользовательСсылка.Пароль = Объект.Пароль;
                ПользовательСсылка.ПолноеИмя = Объект.Наименование;
                ПользовательСсылка.Роли.очистить();
                Если Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Администратор тогда
                    ПользовательСсылка.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Администратор);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Менеджер тогда
                    ПользовательСсылка.Роли.Добавить (Метаданные.Роли.Менеджер);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = перечисления.Роли.Мастер тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Мастер);
                ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Мастер тогда
                    НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Мастер);
                КонецЕсли;
            Иначе
                Сообщ = Новый СообщениеПользователю;
                Сообщ.Текст = "Пользователь с таким именем уже существует";
                Сообщ.Сообщить();
                Отказ = Истина;
            КонецЕсли;
        КонецЕсли;

        Иначе
            НовыйПользователь = ПользователиИнформационнойБазы.СоздатьПользователя();
            НовыйПользователь.Имя = Объект.Логин;
            НовыйПользователь.Пароль = Объект.Пароль;
            НовыйПользователь.ПолноеИмя = Объект.Наименование;
            Если Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Администратор тогда
                НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Администратор);
            ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Менеджер тогда
                ПользовательСсылка.Роли.Добавить (Метаданные.Роли.Менеджер);
            ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = перечисления.Роли.Мастер тогда
                НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Мастер);
            ИначеЕсли Объект.Роль = Перечисления.Роли.Мастер тогда
                НовыйПользователь.Роли.Добавить(Метаданные.Роли.Мастер);
        КонецЕсли;
            НовыйПользователь.ПоказыватьВСпискеВыбора = Ложь;
            НовыйПользователь.Записать();
            ТекущийОбъект.УникальныйИдентификатор = НовыйПользователь.УникальныйИдентификатор;
        КонецЕсли;
    КонецПроцедуры
   ```